# Search multiple GeoServer layers by conditions

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I need a bit of help with GeoServer and querying information.

For example, I would like to search GeoServer for Locations where Location has specific fields:

My build-up query would look like:

```
 WHERE type ILIKE 'Gas'   OR  (   borehole_s ILIKE 'Prod'   AND   planned_td ILike '0'   )  )
```

type, borehole_se & planned_td are fields of Features on Layers, but I would like to search across multiple layers.

Is something like that even possible? I have read that using CQL Filter is a good set.

My query should look simmilar to this one:

```
layers=layer1,layer2,layer3 cql_filter=layer1.prop_name1 = 1 AND layer2.prop_name2 = 2 OR layer3.prop_name3 = 3
```

Is that possible with geoserver ?

Comment: can you give us an example of the GetMap request with the multiple layers and the filters you want to use?

Comment: @IanTurton Hi, I would need something like this: layers=layer1,layer2,layer3
cql_filter=layer1.prop_name1 = 1 AND layer2.prop_name2 = 2 OR layer3.prop_name3 = 3


My initial request looks like this:

 /geoserver/ows/?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&count=100&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsName=EPSG:31256&format_options=id_policy:true&typeName=omv_workspace:Germany_Borehole&request=GetFeature

Comment: @IanTurton Is that even possible to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a CQL filter for each layer in your request by separating them with `;`

So for your example:

```
layers=layer1,layer2,layer3&filter=prop_name1=1;prop_name2=2;prop_name3=3
```

Each filter element is independent of the other filters so you don't have to option of using AND or OR to chain them.

Comment: thank you for answering :)